# How to render a controller from a view?

Tags: sails.js, ejs

I would like to make a render controller from a view. Like's twig engine on Symfony2 but with EJS engine on sails.js :

```
{{ render(controller('BundleName:Action')) }}
```

Is that possible ?

Thanks !

Comment: This would expose the business logic.Why would you render a controller from view? Usually a view is rendered from a controller.

Comment: I know but that's part of my site that repeated on all page.

Answer (score 0):

What your specifically asking is a little confusing. You might expand your answer to include what information your looking for. Are you looking for the controller logic / data to be injected in your current view file, or are you looking for simply the view file to be rendered absent the controller logic?

If you need both the controller logic and the view page replicated in some fashion then you probably need a different approach.

I would suggest putting the logic in a policy and either use response.render('viewTemplate') in each of your controllers for the specific view page, or include the page as a partial in your other view pages (this would change depending on your view engine)